# gradle version is not shown correctly gradle -v

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am very new with gradle. My Ubuntu box 14.04 has gradle installed by default. When I do `gradle -v`. I see following output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.10
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2013-12-17 09:28:15 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     36ced393628875ff15575fa03d16c1349ffe8bb6

Groovy:       1.8.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013
Ivy:          2.2.0
JVM:          1.7.0_79 (Oracle Corporation 24.79-b02)
OS:           Linux 3.13.0-57-generic amd64
```

I tried to upgrade gradle to latest version using following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cwchien/gradle
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-cache search gradle
sudo apt-get install gradle-2.5
```

After the upgrade, I provided `grade -v` command in console. It still shows me "Gradle 1.10".

Is there any easy to find what is causing this?

thanks for your help.

Comment: When you install `gradle-2.5`? Can you run `gradle-2.5`? If so, can you show us `which gradle` and `which gradle-2.5`? Besides, you can create the gradle wrapper: `gradle wrapper --gradle-version 2.4`.

Comment: I deleted the gradle folder in Ubuntu. Then, added new gradle path to my environment variable. It solved my problem.

Comment: Either post your answer or delete your question.